# Is it possible to run an Azure pipeline agent for build iOS app on Linux?

Tags: ios, azure-pipelines

I have created a self hosted agent pool. It gives three options for OS. I want to run xcodebuild on the pipeline, which currently I using the Microsoft hosted agent. Is it possible to connect a self hosted agent running on Linux to the pipeline and run Xcode build? Or should I require a mac machine to run the agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically boils down to: "can you run xcode on linux". No, you cant.

also, according to apple eula you need to run macos on mac hardware.